# DAX formula working in Power BI but not PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I used the new quick measure feature in Power BI to create the below DAX formula. This is a running total based on a Period column that is in the format P01, P02, P03,...P12.

```
YTD = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Combined Data'[Period Value]),
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED('Combined Data'[Period]),
            ISONORAFTER('Combined Data'[Period], MAX('Combined Data'[Period]), DESC)
        )
    )
```

This works perfectly in Power BI. I am trying to replicate this data model in PowerPivot so I can work on the same model in Excel. However the same DAX formula in PowerPivot returns an error that the MAX function can only be used on numeric data.

Data has been imported to the data model using Power Query with exactly the same script as in Power BI.

Why is the same DAX code not being treated in the same way in both programs?

Comment: PowerBI automatically detects data types. Check "Applied steps" in query editor in PowerBI, perhaps some are missing in PowerPivot?

Comment: All the same :(

The steps are all exactly the same as I copied over the M code from Power BI to PowerQuery.

It seems like DAX functions in PowerPivot handle text in a different way to Power BI which is odd.